Gratis Windows app to extract individual tracks from a music DVD (and auto-name them, if possible)
Gratis Windows app to extract individual tracks from a music DVD, and auto-name them, if possible.
The best that I can do is to use VLC to get one long MP3 track.
I would like a gratis Windows app that can:

Extract the audio from a music DVD
Split that into separate tracks, maybe based on silence, preferably based on some disc ID encoded on the DVD
Auto-name the tracks

One app would be ideal. I would accept a series of apps, one to do each part, but, please, only post if you have already used these and know them to work. I have already wasted half a day trying various recommendations.
Hmm, maybe I don't want a ripper or convertor, but a movie editing app whcih can extract the soundtrack

When you say a "music DVD" do you mean a DVD full of music or a video DVD with the videos to match the tracks.

I mean full music videos, like a movie or TV, and I want to ignore the video and extract onluy the audio. Hmm, maybe I don't want a ripper or convertor, but a movie editing app whcih can extract the soundtrack

First a legal bit
Copying content from Commercial DVDs that you own for your own personal use is legal in some legislative locations and illegal in others - you will need to check what applies where you are & for why you are doing it. Copying from those owned by others or for distribution to other people is illegal in most/all places. To add even more confusion if the video has been recorded by you then the legality of doing anything further with is depends on the source & content - if you recorded it from an online or on air source then it may well be illegal - even if you created it, e.g. a camera recording of a karaoke session then the material may be covered by copyright.
Some manufacturers put in place copy protection &/or region limitation encryption, etc. there is a huge debate about this, especially since there have been cases where the DVDs install virus like spyware when you play them. You might need to use a tool such as WinX DVD Ripper even where what you are doing is legal, (there are free & paid versions) & such a tool may be able to extract/rip the audio only for you.
Extracting Audio & Splitting the DVD into separate tracks
You could simply install and use FFMPEG but many people find the very extensive list of command line options a little bit much to cope with.
Instead I would suggest installing the following, (all free, gratis & open source):

Download & Install Python (64 bit if your machine supports it) from the python downloads page - the installer defaults will normally make sense.
In a new command prompt execute: py -m pip install --update pip setuptools wheel to make sure that some of the fundamental tools are up to date.
Then execute pip install moviepy Pillow pygame numpy to get moviepy - N.B. moviepy uses FFRMPEG under the hood which it will download and install at an appropriate location the first time that you use moviepy so you need be connected to the internet that first time.
Personally I would also pip install ipython (this gives you a more helpful interactive python shell) and one of the free python IDEs such as Thonney, Eric or Spyder.

The next thing that you need to look at is how your music video DVDs are organised. If you look at the file structure of the DVDs there will normally be a folder called VIDEO_TS containing some .VOB files. Not all DVDs have the same file arrangement - some will have a single .VOB file with all of the video in, some will have multiple files .VOB files with one containing most of the video content and some will have one .VOB file per chapter/track. In the last case you will just need to extract the audio from each track & name them appropriately.
With moviepy you can easily extract the sound from a single video file (one of the .VOB files or a ripped .mp4 file.
from moviepy.editor import *  # Get all of the moviepy editor methods

vidioclip = VideoFileClip("path_to_video_file")
audioclip = videoclip.audio
# If you already have one long/large audio file use:
# audioclip = AudioFileClip("path_to_audio_file")
audioclip.write_audiofile("filename.mp3", bitrate="500k") # Bitrate determines the size & quality

If you end up with one file that you need to split you can either use the track = audioclip.subclip(start, end) method with manually determined times in seconds or as a string such as "00:05:20.25" or you can use logic such as an inverse of what is shown in the example of splitting a soccer game based on loudness to detect a few seconds of near silence between tracks.
Naming the tracks
Obviously you can manually type in the track names but you could potentially use python to scrape the details of the DVD from a web site or service but that would be a whole different question.

Excellent, and lengthy, answer, as usual. Thanks, Steve.  I especially like how you managed to work Python into it ;-)
